# Getting VPC-ID for specific VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

after the VPC is created, how I can grep only 1 VPC-ID from specific VPC by aws ec2 describe-vpcs, so that VPC ID can be passed inside the script for the next step, I know I can see it manually from that command or from AWS console,

for example:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids |grep VpcId
            "VpcId": "vpc-00a0338c2f671a77c",
            "VpcId": "vpc-0b3697513d5987516",
            "VpcId": "vpc-061e25f5f78877798",
```

it gives me all of them, or:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids |grep -i ansible
                    "Value": "ANSIBLE_VPC",
```

but I need only to get the VPC-ID for that specific VPC from command.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "get the VPC-ID for that specific VPC from command"? Are you saying that you issued a `aws ec2 create-vpc` command just prior to this? Or are you seeking a particular VPC based upon the value of a tag?

Comment: and the same thing for subnet, IGW, router, security group and NACL

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "and the same thing...". Does the answer below satisfy your question? If not, please Edit your question to clarify what you are seeking.

Comment: Note that using `grep` to find resource IDs is fragile and should be avoided. You should use the `--query` option that's native to the awscli, or you can pipe the awscli output into a third-party tool named `jq` which can parse the JSON.

Answer (score 6):

If you just issued a `create-vpc` command, then the VPC ID of that VPC would have been returned in response to that command:

Output:

```
{
    "Vpc": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-5EXAMPLE",
        "State": "pending",
        "VpcId": "vpc-0a60eb65b4EXAMPLE",    <-- This is the VPC ID
        "OwnerId": "123456789012",
        "InstanceTenancy": "default",
        "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
        "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
            {
                "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-07501b79ecEXAMPLE",
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                "CidrBlockState": {
                    "State": "associated"
                }
            }
        ],
        "IsDefault": false,
        "Tags": []
    }
}
```

Thus, you could create the VPC and store its ID like this:

```sh
$ ID=`aws ec2 create-vpc --cidr-block 10.0.0.0/16 --query Vpc.VpcId --output text`

$ echo $ID
vpc-0fb4d08f9d6501e94
```

If, instead, you are seeking the VPC ID for a VPC given its Name tag, you could use:

```sh
$ ID=`aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text`

$ echo $ID
vpc-0fb4d08f9d6501e94
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use just the aws cli for this, with filters and query:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query "Vpcs[].VpcId" --output text"
```

Or you can use a mix of the `--filters` command with grep to accomplish your task:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC | grep VpcId | grep -oh "vpc-\w*"
```